# Android - load image from path

Tags: android, image, file, path

In my project I have image localized in

```
app\src\main\res\drawable\informations\angry_face.png
```

When I want to load it using

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("app\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\informations\\angry_face.png");
this.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Error occurs:

> Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   app\src\main\res\drawable\informations\angry_face.png:  open failed:
>   ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Question is: How to set the path to this resource? 
**Thanks for help :)**

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the resources wrongly:

Try this instead:

```
Bitmap myAngryImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.angry_face);
```

Comment: Good idea. But what to do when I want to organize my images into subfolders? How to load images in this kind of situation?